# Is const_cast(iterator->second) safe?

Tags: c++

I want to know if this code is safe and doesnt have any undefined behavior.

```
 QueueMap::const_iterator it = m_3playersQueue.find(s->m_GameCode);
 if(it == m_3playersQueue.end())
 {
     std::deque<Session*> stack;
     stack.push_back(s);

     m_3playersQueue[s->m_GameCode] = stack;
     return;
 }

 const_cast<std::deque<Session*>&>(it->second).push_back(s);

 QueueMap is of type std::tr1::unordered_map< uint32, std::deque<Session*> >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. Even if a `const_iterator` is different from an `iterator`, the objects in the map are the same. As long as all the map contents were created as mutable `std::deque<Session*>` objects, it's OK to cast the constness away.

Of course, it's possible you're violating some invariant the constness was meant to convey, but that's possible with any `const_cast` taken in isolation.

Answer (score 4):

Your code contradicts itself. Just use `QueueMap::iterator` instead of `QueueMap::const_iterator`.

What you're doing is explicitly making it const, then `const_cast`ing away the `const`ness. Why bother?

Comment: If m_3playersQueeu is const, then `find` returns a `const_iterator`, presumably.

Comment: I know about it. I know that i can just simply change const_iterator to iterator. But that code was interesting me. const_iterator is a little bit faster than iterator - thats the reason

Comment: @quarry: Sounds like you may be prematurely optimizing.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi just my instinct x) but the idea that const_iterator is faster isnt mine.

Comment: @quarry: well, whoever came up with the idea, there's zero reason to expect it to be true. And that's one reason why you should *measure* when optimizing.

Comment: @auarry: I don't think there's any reason to believe that `const_iterator` is faster. For the record, since `m_3playersQueue` isn't actually `const` then your code doesn't have undefined behavior.  However, Mahmoud's advice is still correct - type things as they they are and as you expect to use them.

Answer (score 1):

The code might be a bit simpler to understand in the following form: Always insert and update:

```
std::pair<QueueMap::iterator, bool> p =
  m_3playersQueue.insert(std::make_pair(s->m_GameCode, std::deque<Session*>()));

p.first->second.push_back(s);
```

The only inefficiency is when the element already exists, in which case you have to throw away an empty `deque`. But small, short-lived heap allocations aren't usually expensive, so you should profile carefully to justify more complicated code. Think about how long it would take your successor to work through and debug your code!